# I want to use Service for Phone number

Tags: android, android-intent, android-intentservice

[See the view here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YK9Rdf85OuEqO3jYr1YiJBUylqq4k4xH/view?usp=sharing)
I want to do this only, like when someone click on a number format, then my app should also be visible in the OPEN WITH list...

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:autoLink="phone"` into the TextView.

For example:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvMsg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:autoLink="phone"
    android:textColorLink="@color/purple_500"/>
```

For more info please check these questions: [Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497327/android-make-phone-numbers-clickable-autodetect) and [Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40788608/androidautolink-for-phone-numbers-doesnt-always-work/40820069)